# Durandal subnavigation with Parameters

Tags: javascript, navigation, url-routing, durandal

once again a Durandal question ^^ I'd like to make a subnavigation menu.
The subpage is called per url

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="attr: { href: '#customer/'+ id }">Open</a>
```

The shell.js routes this to the **customers/shell2.js** (the child router) that you can see here:

```
define(['plugins/router', 'knockout', 'utility', 'logger', 'datacontext'], function (router, ko, utility, logger, datacontext) {
var displayName = 'Customer';
var cId = ko.observable(0);

var childRouter = router.createChildRouter()
    .makeRelative({ moduleId: 'viewmodels/customers' , route: 'customer/:id/'});

return {
    router: childRouter,
    cId: cId,
    displayName: displayName,
    activate: activate
};

function activate() {
    cId(parseInt(router.activeInstruction().params[0]));
    childRouter.map([
        {
            route: ['', 'overview'],
            moduleId: 'overview',
            name: 'Overview',
            hash: '#customer/' + cId() + '/overview',
            nav: false,
            settings: {}
        },
        {
            route: 'sessions',
            moduleId: 'sessions',
            name: 'Sitzungen',
            hash: '#customer/' + cId() + '/sessions',
            nav: false,
            settings: {}
        }
    ]).buildNavigationModel();
}
});
```

In short: I want the link to be like #customer/17/overview with 17 being the route parameter for calling the subnavigation.

When i call the url #customer/17, the content of the route is displayed, but not the subnavigation. Moreover the urls #customer/17/overview and #customer/17/session don't work...
Has someone a working example where the subnav is built with parameters?

EDIT:
**shell.js**

```
define(['plugins/router', 'knockout' ,'session', 'toastr','logger', 'durandal/app']
, function (router, ko, session, toastr, logger, app) {

var routes= [
    {   route: '',
        moduleId: 'login',
        name: 'Login',
        hash: '',
        nav: false,
        settings: {}
    },
    {   route: 'dashboard',
        moduleId: 'dashboard/dashboard',
        name: 'Dashboard',
        hash: '#dashboard',
        nav: true,
        settings: {}
    },
    {   route: 'customers',
        moduleId: 'customers/customers',
        name: 'Customers',
        hash: '#customers',
        nav: true,
        settings: {}
    },
    {   route: 'customer/:id',
        moduleId: 'customers/shell2',
        name: 'customer',
        hash: '',
        nav: false,
        settings: {}
    },
    {   route: 'logout',
        moduleId: 'logout',
        name: 'Logout',
        hash: '',
        nav: true,
        settings: {}
    }];

return {
    activate: activate,
    router: router,
    session: session,
    app: app
};

function activate() {
    router.makeRelative({moduleId:'viewmodels'})
        .map(routes)
        .buildNavigationModel() // Finds all nav routes and makes them ready
        .mapUnknownRoutes('notfound', 'notfound');

    router.activate();
}
});
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your shell.js and parent router please?

Comment: Done... do you think the problem is within shell.js?

Comment: I just needed to see the shell to get a better idea of your current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem was really in the parent **shell.js**. I changed the route to the child shell this way:

```
{ 
  // add *details for splat route, even when there is nothing named 'details'
  route: 'customer/:id*details',
  moduleId: 'customer/shell2',
  name: 'Customer',
  nav: true
}
```

The childrouter **shell2.js** looks like this:

```
define(['plugins/router', 'knockout'], function (router, ko) {
var displayName = 'Customer';
var customerId = ko.observable(0);

var childRouter = router.createChildRouter();

return {
    router: childRouter,
    customerId: customerId,
    displayName: displayName,
    activate: activate
};

function activate(newCustomerId) {
    customerId(newCustomerId);
    // resetting, otherwise every activation adds elements
    childRouter.reset();

    // individual mapping on each activation, so the id is updated in the hashes
    childRouter.makeRelative({ moduleId: 'viewmodels/customers' , route: 'customer/:id/'})
        .map([
        {
            route: '',
            moduleId: 'overview',
            name: 'overview',
            hash: '#customer/'+ v6Id(),
            nav: true,
        },
        {
            route: 'sessions',
            moduleId: 'sessions',
            name: 'Sessions',
            hash: '#customer/'+ v6Id() + '/sessions',
            nav: true,
        }
        ])
        .buildNavigationModel();
}
});
```

P.S.: Don't forget to set 'nav' to true, that was the reason why my navigation didn't show up.

P.S.2: Perhaps you should add properties to each route to differ in the view between main-nav and sub-nav.